# In ActiveModel::Serializer, how to render json-api relationships with id only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

Using `ActiveModel::Serializer` (0.10.0.rc3) using the `json-api` adapter, how can I render relationships with id only by default?

Consider my serializer

```
class ASerializer < Api::V1::BaseSerializer
  attributes :id, :name
  has_many :bs
end
```

However, that renders all the attributes defined in `BSerializer`, too. I could define a `BMiniSerializer` to only render the `id`, and use it as 
`has_many :bs, serializer: BMiniSerializer`, but that means I'd have to do it for all Models and add it to all Serializers. Is there a more elegant, default way?

**Edit**

I suppose this is what `:include` and `:fields` are for. Unfortunately it seems that -- since I'm using a different namespace for my API-controllers and serializers from my model I need to specify the serializers for the associated models explicitly for `:include` and `:fields` to work.

Answer (score 2):

Let me show it on the example of `Order` and `OrderItem` classes. I also assume we are using version `0.10.0.rc3`, because in `0.9.x` it works another way.

You should customize your json by passing parameters to serializer. For instance:

```
render json: @orders, short: true
```

Parameter `:short` can be accessed in initializer of `OrderSerializer` now:

```
def initialize(object, options = {})
  @short = options[:short]
  super
end
```

we save this parameter as `@short` instance variable. Now we can define `order_items` function, which will include only `ids` when called with `short: true`:

```
def order_items
  if @short
    object.order_items.map{|x| [:id,x.id]}.to_h
  else
    object.order_items
  end
end
```

Comment: I have not tried this approach yet, but it seems it would be cumbersome for a function like `order_items` would have to be defined for every association and every model? Or is that inheritable somehow?